How to Read and Write with Raspberry Pi Pico I2C protocol?
I am trying to implement a simple I2C to do the following:

Pico1 (Master) Sends the letter 'M' to Pico2 (Slave) and prints Master Sending: M.
Pico2 (Slave) Receives the Letter 'M' from Pico1 (Master) prints Slave Received: M
Pico2 (Slave) Sends the letter 'S' to Pico1 (Master) and prints Slave Sending: S.
Pico1 (Master) Receives the Letter 'M' from Pico2 (Slave) prints Master Received: S

Master Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/i2c.h"

#define I2C_PORT i2c0
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x42 // I2C address of the slave
#define DATA_LENGTH 1 // Length of data to send/receive

int main() {
    // Initialize chosen serial port
    stdio_init_all();

    // Initialize I2C port at 100 kHz
    i2c_init(I2C_PORT, 100 * 1000);
    gpio_set_function(4, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_set_function(5, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_pull_up(4);
    gpio_pull_up(5);

    char send_data = 'M'; // Data to send to the slave
    char receive_data;    // Buffer to store received data from the slave

    while (true) {
        // Step 1: Send the letter 'M' to the slave
        i2c_write_blocking(I2C_PORT, SLAVE_ADDRESS, &send_data, DATA_LENGTH, false);
        printf("Master: Sent '%c' to slave\n", send_data);

        // Wait for a moment to give slave time to respond
        sleep_ms(500);

        // Step 4: Receive the letter 'S' from the slave
        i2c_read_blocking(I2C_PORT, SLAVE_ADDRESS, &receive_data, DATA_LENGTH, false);
        printf("Master: Received '%c' from slave\n", receive_data);

        // Wait a bit before repeating the process
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}

Slave Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/i2c.h"

#define I2C_PORT i2c0
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x42 // I2C slave address
#define DATA_LENGTH 1 // Length of data to send/receive

int main() {
    // Initialize the serial port
    stdio_init_all();

    // Initialize I2C in slave mode
    i2c_init(I2C_PORT, 100 * 1000);
    gpio_set_function(4, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_set_function(5, GPIO_FUNC_I2C);
    gpio_pull_up(4);
    gpio_pull_up(5);
    i2c_set_slave_mode(I2C_PORT, true, SLAVE_ADDRESS);

    char receive_data;   // Buffer to store received data from the master
    char send_data = 'S'; // Data to send to the master

    while (true) {
        // Step 2: Receive the letter 'M' from the master
        if (i2c_get_read_available(I2C_PORT) > 0) {
            i2c_read_raw_blocking(I2C_PORT, &receive_data, DATA_LENGTH);
            printf("Slave: Received '%c' from master\n", receive_data);
        }

        // Wait a moment to simulate processing
        sleep_ms(500);

        // Step 3: Send the letter 'S' back to the master
        i2c_write_raw_blocking(I2C_PORT, &send_data, DATA_LENGTH);
        printf("Slave: Sent '%c' back to master\n", send_data);

        // Wait a bit before repeating the process
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }

   return 0;
}

In the Terminal for the Master it doesn't print anything. In the terminal for the Slave it prints the following:
Slave output:
Slave: Sent 'S' back to master
Slave: Sent 'S' back to master
Slave: Sent 'S' back to master

How can the master send, receive and print the data in the terminal?

"Pico2 (Slave) Sends the letter 'S' to Pico1 (Master)". The I2C slave can only respond to a master's request, not just send something whenever it likes. When the I2C master does "i2c_write_blocking", the slave will receive a I2C_SLAVE_RECEIVE slave event and has to accept the data (e.g. save it internally)and ACK it. When the master does "i2c_read_blocking", the slave receives a "I2C_SLAVE_REQUEST" request and has to respond immediately or do clock stretching. You can't just decide to wait 500ms in the slave before sending something back to the master. This is not UART.

Look at https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/master/i2c/slave_mem_i2c/slave_mem_i2c.c specifically and i2c_slave_init(i2c0, I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS, &i2c_slave_handler);, i2c_slave_handler(). That's how you should implement your I2C slave. With those callbacks. not just sleep_ms() and  i2c_write_raw_blocking() whenever you want.

@MaximilianGerhardt I referred to the code you suggested. And I wanted to test the code if it works before I start analyzing it. The code itself doesn't work. When I upload the code on the Pico the terminal doesn't even see the ttyACM0 which is the Pico board. Have you tested this code before?

The USB not showing up could be because you have to enable USB for std-output and not UART in the CMakeLists.txt: https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/master/hello_world/usb/CMakeLists.txt#L9C1-L11C40

No because I tested the USB with a simple project and it works fine. I also made sure that the CMakeLists file is correct. Also checked the pins are connected correctly everything is fine on that end.
